# ¿Como implementar OnFragmentInteractionListener en android?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy tratando de insertar un fragment dentro de un Navigation Drawer, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me dice la aplicacion que se detuvo y checando los errores me dice que la causa es:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.example.aguil.visionecologica.Clases_Principales.Lateral@719b5ce
>   must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

El codigo de mi Navigation Drawer donde hago la conexión con los fragments

```
package com.example.aguil.visionecologica.Clases_Principales;
public class Lateral extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lateral);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Cargar(new Prin_Eco());
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lateral, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void Cargar(Fragment fragmento){
    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contendor_principal, fragmento).commit();
    }
}
```

El codigo XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_lateral" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contendor_principal"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbarview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

el LogCat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.aguil.visionecologica, PID: 30735
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aguil.visionecologica/com.example.aguil.visionecologica.Clases_Principales.Lateral}: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.aguil.visionecologica.Clases_Principales.Lateral@719b5ce must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.aguil.visionecologica.Clases_Principales.Lateral@719b5ce must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                  at com.example.aguil.visionecologica.Fragments.Prin_Eco.onAttach(Prin_Eco.java:84)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1404)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1190)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1073)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:117)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2407)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2365)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2272)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3271)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3227)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:610)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1270)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6689)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2622)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Debes de implementarlo en el Activity donde lo llamas. Por ejemplo "public class tuclase implements nombredetufragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener"

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que sobreescribir el método `OnFragmentInteractionListener` en la misma actividad que implementa el `fragment`. Puedes dejarlo vacío:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
}
```